# How can you move or copy specific files from a list of text files

Tags: files, xargs, mv

So I have a directory of like 200 of the the following types of files:

```
gre_6_c1_d34567.h3
gre_6_c1_d95543.h3
gre_6_c1_d42354.h3
gre_6_c1_d01452.h3
gre_6_c1_d23168.h3
gre_6_c1_435435.h3
```

The only difference between these files is the numbers after `d`.  I have a text file that only contains the `d` number for like 50 of these files.  If I could get the entire file name I would but this text file is the output of another script.  Is there a way I can move these files to another directory using the `d` number from the text file?

Answer (score 0):

Using  `sed` `e` flag :

```
sed 's|^\(.*\)$|mv gre_6_c1_\1.h3 newdir/|e' list.txt
```

Above will move the files to `newdir/` change it accordingly.

I assume on list.txt the number are as below separated by new line:

```
d34567
d23168
```

Run this to confirm:

```
sed 's|^\(.*\)$|mv gre_6_c1_\1.h3 newdir/|' list.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

With `bash` 4, you could load an array with file names derived from the numbers in the "driver" file and then use the `-t` option of GNU `mv` to move them into a directory at one shot. Note

```
#read contents of driver_file into an array arr using mapfile
mapfile -t arr <driver_file

#define prefix and suffix variables
prefix=gre_6_c1_d
suffix=.h3

#prefix each array element
arr=("${arr[@]/#/$prefix}")

#suffix each array element
arr=("${arr[@]/%/$suffix}")

#use GNU mv's -t facility to move files into newdir
mv -t newdir/ "${arr[@]}"
```

Comment: I just wrote my first bash script yesterday so this is a little over my head.  Can you explain it a little more in depth?

Comment: @e1v1s, some explanation added

Answer (score 0):

Reading the numbers from the file one by one and doing the move (assumes a POSIX shell):

```sh
while read -r number; do
   name="gre_6_c1_d$number.h3"
   [ -f "$name" ] && mv -i "gre_6_c1_d$number.h3" /other/directory
done <number.list
```

This also makes sure that the number yields the name of a file existing in the current directory before moving it to the other directory.  The `mv -i` command will furthermore ask for confirmation before overwriting an existing file.

---

Since this question was tagged with [xargs](/questions/tagged/xargs), we could ask `xargs` to generate the list of numbers for us:

```sh
xargs sh -c '
    for number do
        name="gre_6_c1_d$number.h3"
        [ -f "$name" ] && mv "gre_6_c1_d$number.h3" /other/directory
    done' sh <number.list
```

This wouldn't speed anything up, but if your `xargs` provides a `-P` flag for running things in parallel, you could get a small speed boost:

```sh
xargs -P 5 -n 10 -h sh -c '
    for number do
        name="gre_6_c1_d$number.h3"
        [ -f "$name" ] && mv "gre_6_c1_d$number.h3" /other/directory
    done' sh <number.list
```

This would start at most five copies of the loop in parallel, and give each at most ten numbers each in batches.